# ParserError: Expected token Semicolon got 'Period'

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// 'FIXED' 'Example Fixed Supply Token' token contract

//

// Symbol      : FIXED

// Name        : Example Fixed Supply Token

// Total supply: 1,000,000.000000000000000000

// Decimals    : 18

//

// Enjoy.

//

// (c) BokkyPooBah / Bok Consulting Pty Ltd 2017. The MIT Licence.

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Safe maths

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

library SafeMath {

    function add(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {

        c = a + b;

        require(c >= a);

    }

    function sub(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {

        require(b <= a);

        c = a - b;

    }

    function mul(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {

        c = a * b;

        require(a == 0 || c / a == b);

    }

    function div(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {

        require(b > 0);

        c = a / b;

    }

}



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// ERC Token Standard #20 Interface

// https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

contract ERC20Interface {

    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);

    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);

    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);


    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);

    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);

}



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Contract function to receive approval and execute function in one call

//

// Borrowed from MiniMeToken

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

contract ApproveAndCallFallBack {

    function receiveApproval(address from, uint256 tokens, address token, bytes data) public;

}



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Owned contract

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

contract Owned {

    address public owner;

    address public newOwner;


    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed _from, address indexed _to);


    function constructor() public {

        owner = msg.sender;

    }


    modifier onlyOwner {

        require(msg.sender == owner);

        _;

    }


    function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {

        newOwner = _newOwner;

    }

    function acceptOwnership() public {

        require(msg.sender == newOwner);

        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);

        owner = newOwner;

        newOwner = address(0);

    }

}



// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// ERC20 Token, with the addition of symbol, name and decimals and an

// initial fixed supply

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

contract FixedSupplyToken is ERC20Interface, Owned {

    using SafeMath for uint;


    string public symbol;

    string public  name;

    uint8 public decimals;

    uint public _totalSupply;


    mapping(address => uint) balances;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Constructor

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function constructor() public {

        symbol = "FIXED";

        name = "Example Fixed Supply Token";

        decimals = 18;

        _totalSupply = 1000000 * 10**uint(decimals);

        balances[owner] = _totalSupply;

        emit Transfer(address(0), owner, _totalSupply);

    }



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Total supply

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint) {

        return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];

    }



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Get the token balance for account `tokenOwner`

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance) {

        return balances[tokenOwner];

    }



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Transfer the balance from token owner's account to `to` account

    // - Owner's account must have sufficient balance to transfer

    // - 0 value transfers are allowed

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(tokens);

        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);

        return true;

    }



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Token owner can approve for `spender` to transferFrom(...) `tokens`

    // from the token owner's account

    //

    // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md

    // recommends that there are no checks for the approval double-spend attack

    // as this should be implemented in user interfaces 

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {

        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;

        Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);

        return true;

    }



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Transfer `tokens` from the `from` account to the `to` account

    // 

    // The calling account must already have sufficient tokens approve(...)-d

    // for spending from the `from` account and

    // - From account must have sufficient balance to transfer

    // - Spender must have sufficient allowance to transfer

    // - 0 value transfers are allowed

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {

        balances[from] = balances[from].sub(tokens);

        allowed[from][msg.sender] = allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(tokens);

        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);

        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);

        return true;

    }



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Returns the amount of tokens approved by the owner that can be

    // transferred to the spender's account

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining) {

        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];

    }



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Token owner can approve for `spender` to transferFrom(...) `tokens`

    // from the token owner's account. The `spender` contract function

    // `receiveApproval(...)` is then executed

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes data) public returns (bool success) {

        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;

        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);

        emit ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, this, data);

        return true;

    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Don't accept ETH

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function () public payable {

        revert();

    }



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Owner can transfer out any accidentally sent ERC20 tokens

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function transferAnyERC20Token(address tokenAddress, uint tokens) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {

        return ERC20Interface(tokenAddress).transfer(owner, tokens);

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `emit` from the start of that line and that should fix it.